# EF mapping of composite key

Tags: entity-framework-4

```cs
public class MyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyCode>
{
  public MyConfiguration()
  {
    HasKey(c => new { c.MyCodeId, c.EffectiveDateFrom, c.EffectiveDateTo });
    Property(c => c.MyCodeId).HasColumnName("MyCode");
    Property(c => c.EffectiveDateFrom).HasColumnName("MyEffectiveDateFrom");
    Property(c => c.EffectiveDateTo).HasColumnName("MyEffectiveDateTo");

    ToTable("My_CODES");

    HasMany(d => d.MyGroups).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(k => k.MyCodeID);
  }
}
```

This is my configuration class in EF4.

I have defined the “MyGroups” property of type `IList<MyGroup>`.

“MyGroup” class doesn’t have the “EffectiveDateFrom” and “EffectiveDateTo” property.

Run time following exception thrown:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint:  The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Query:
How to create this kind of mapping in EF4, when all the columns used in parent is not available in the child table?

Comment: What does this look like in the database? How does a `MyGroup` record know which record it refers to if `MyCodeId` does not uniquely identify a `MyCode` record?

Comment: MyGroup table has composite key consiste of column MyCodeId, GroupNumber and TabNumber

Comment: Is the database yours to change? If so, add a single primary key and let the other fields serve as an alternate key. Meaningful primary keys are a nuisance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create such mapping because it is not valid. Foreign key in dependent the entity must contain all components of composite primary key defined in the principal entity.